# ASP.Net Core web app with SSO configured - allow anonymous access to a single API endpoint

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, openid-connect

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 web app using server-side Blazor, Razor pages, configured with SSO (Microsoft Entra), deployed in an Azure environment. All works fine, but I am accessing an external app that requires me to provide an unprotected API endpoint for a callback.

The original setup was:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options => {
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});
```

I have added the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute to the API controller, and also tried variants of `[Authorize("AnonymousPolicy")]`.

I have tried MANY variations of modifying authentication and authorization, but have so far been unable to implement anonymous access to my API endpoint.

The current code is:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options => {
        options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
    })
    .AddCookie("Cookies")
    .AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => {
        options.Authority = $"{azureAdConfig.Instance}/{azureAdConfig.TenantId}/v2.0";      // The URL of the Identity Provider
        options.ClientId = azureAdConfig.ClientId;                                         
        options.ClientSecret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";                 
        options.ResponseType = "code id_token";                                            
        options.SaveTokens = true;                                                         
    })
    .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, AnonymousSchemeHandler>("AnonymousScheme", "Allow Anonymous",
    options => {
        options.ForwardDefaultSelector = context => {
            return context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api/XXXXX") ?                "AnonymousScheme" : OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        };
    });
```

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("OpenIdPolicy", policy =>
            policy.Requirements.Add(new SchemeRequirement(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)));
    options.AddPolicy("AnonymousPolicy", policy =>
            policy.Requirements.Add(new SchemeRequirement("AnonymousScheme")));
    options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .AddAuthenticationSchemes(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, "AnonymousScheme")
        .Build();
});
```

When I run the app with the above code and hit the endpoint, I get an exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found. The default schemes can be set using either AddAuthentication(string defaultScheme) or AddAuthentication(Action configureOptions).
>
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.ChallengeAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme, AuthenticationProperties properties)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler.HandleAsync(RequestDelegate next, HttpContext context, AuthorizationPolicy policy, PolicyAuthorizationResult authorizeResult)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)`

Any suggestions for modification are very welcome.